# How to set a Radio Group Tab as optional to complete envelope

Tags: docusignapi

In using the Rest API v2, there seems to be no way of making a Radio Group Tab in a DocuSign envelope "optional," which is to say that the envelope can be completed without selecting a radio button if one is there. A SignHereTab, on the other hand, has an "optional" parameter which can be set to true. The signature will then not be required to complete the envelope. Does anyone know if there is a way to do this same functionalilty with Radio Group Tabs?

I thought of simply having one of the radio buttons selected by default, but it seems that a radio button can be de-selected... This could be a possible work-around, though.

**Update**

Well, I did find out why my radio buttons could be deselected: it was because I was not assigning values to the radio buttons. Once I set the value property for each radio button, it now cannot be deselected. I still don't think there is a way to make a radio group tab "optional", but setting one of them selected as default probably won't confuse the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In DocuSign you have the ability to add grouped radio buttons as well as checkboxes, the difference between them is that with grouped radio buttons one and exactly one selection must be chosen, however with checkboxes any number of them (including 0) can be selected.

One possible workaround though is using **Conditional Fields**.  With conditional fields you can hide/make visible certain tabs, based on the value of another envelope tab.  For instance, you could set things up such that if the recipient checks a certain checkbox, then and only then does your radio group show up.  Without it checked the recipient is not required to select a radio option and in fact they won't even see the radio buttons.

To use conditional fields you simply need to set these two properties on your radio group:

```
conditionalParentLabel
conditionalParentValue
```

**conditionalParentLabel**:  For conditional fields this is the TabLabel of the parent tab that controls this tab’s visibility.

**conditionalParentValue**:  For conditional fields this is the Value of the parent tab that controls this tab’s visibility.  If the parent tab is a Checkbox, Radio button, Optional Signature, or Optional Initial use “on” as the value to show that the parent tab is active.

For more information please see the DocuSign API Guides:
http://www.docusign.com/developer-center/documentation

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, there is an error in the API documentation. Like you mentioned above, it says "If the parent tab is a Checkbox, Radio button, Optional Signature, or Optional Initial use “on” as the value to show that the parent tab is active", but that is wrong for radio buttons. If a Radio Group Tab is the parent, the parentLabel corresponds to the Radio Group Name and the parentValue is the value of the specific radio button you are concerned about.